# Ignore optional columns on save

Tags: entity-framework, forms, asp.net-mvc-3, savechanges, datacolumn

When I update a table from a Form through Autogenerated EF, if I remove some data-columns from the view form because I don't want to be editable, that columns are updated with null value, how can avoid this behavior? I read here: [Entity Framework: Ignore Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737520/entity-framework-ignore-columns) removing it from the model, but not always I want to ignore these datacolumns.

thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asp.net MVC  provide you with `UpdateModel` method, look on the overload

```
protected internal void UpdateModel<TModel>(
TModel model,
string prefix,
string[] includeProperties,
string[] excludeProperties
)
where TModel : class
```

using it you are able to exclude or include particular properties by their names

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to understand how it works, seems the rigth solution

Comment: Excelent! I only have to replace the db.MyTable.Attach(mytable); for UpdateModel<MyTable>(mytable);

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use annotations

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(
    [Bind(Prefix="", Include="field1", Exclude="field2")]MyClass myClass)
{
  ....
```